# Testing React/Jest component with Window.onload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm testing a functional component that uses Window.onload to stay on a certain page. Example of the code

```
function SignUpForm(props) {

  const history = useHistory();
  const {setOnPage } = props;
  window.onload = setOnPage("/registrarse")
```

My test is:

```
import React from 'react'
import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import { screen, render } from '@testing-library/react'

import SignInScreen from './SignInScreen'
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16"

const { shallow } = Enzyme; 

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

describe('Test for login in form', () => {
    test("renders correctly", () => {
        shallow(<SignInScreen/>);
      });
});
```

The error is in the line of Window.onload, I have not been able to find any solution that can help me.

```
setOnPage is not a function
```

Comment: Can you show how do you instantiate your SignUpForm please ? I guess that you don't pass the setOnPage function correctly to this component

Comment: Are you sure that props has a setOnPage property? Add a `console.log({setOnPage})` after `const {setOnPage} = props;` you should get {setOnPage: _f_ } in the console showing it's a function